# CSS flex-direction: column, justify positioning not happening

Tags: html, css

I couldn't find my error for like 40 minutes. What I wanted to achieve is to position some elements, input fields, ect.. using height and display: flex, flex-direction: column and justify-content: space-between. Basic stuff, here is some code

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
    font-family: 16px/1.2 "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #01dbde, #00cfff, #00b8ff 20%, #6a8cff, #fc00ff 100%);
}

form {
    background: #fff;
}

.border-curve {
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 3em 5em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 32rem;
}

.form-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.form-social {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-social button {
    flex: 0 0 48%;
}

.form-field {
}

.form-action {
}

.form-field label,
.form-field input,
.form-action input {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.form-action input {
    border: 0.2em solid #333;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Funny Login Form</title>
        <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <form action="#" method="GET" class="border-curve">
                <fieldset>
                    <p class="form-title">Sign In With</p>

                    <p class="form-social">
                        <button class="border-curve">Facebook</button>
                        <button class="border-curve">Google</button>
                    </p>

                    <p class="form-field">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input class="border-curve" type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="form-field">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input class="border-curve" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="form-action">
                        <input class="border-curve" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is why I can't position my elements in tag fieldset using flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<fieldset>` is a button element so `display: flex` cannot be applied to it. Try placing a div inside of your fieldset which will contain all of your form elements as children and then applying `display: flex` to that.

HTML:

```
 <fieldset>
        <div class="fieldset-content">
            <div>
                <p class="form-title">Sign In With</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="form-social">
                    <button class="border-curve">Facebook</button>
                    <button class="border-curve">Google</button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="form-field">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input class="border-curve" type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="form-field">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="border-curve" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="form-action">
                    <input class="border-curve" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Now that you have your flex items inside of a container that you can apply flex to, you can add in all of your desired flex properties.

CSS:

```
.fieldset-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that fieldset is a button element.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. How should I close my question?

Comment: Click the check mark button on the appropriate question as well as an upvote if you found it to be helpful.

Comment: This will mark your question as answered so that hopefully someone with a similar problem in the future will be able to benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#Styling_with_CSS says that there is an anonymous box that holds the contents of the fieldset. This anonymous box will inherit the display value of the fieldset, but it seems as though other styling will be applied to the fieldset tag itself and not the anonymous box.

If you wrap the current contents of the fieldset in a container div, you can then style that container space-between.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-family: 16px/1.2 "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #01dbde, #00cfff, #00b8ff 20%, #6a8cff, #fc00ff 100%);
}

form {
  background: #fff;
}

.border-curve {
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
  margin: 3em 5em;
}

.fieldset-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 32rem;
}

.form-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.form-social {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-social button {
  flex: 0 0 48%;
}

.form-field {}

.form-action {}

.form-field label,
.form-field input,
.form-action input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.form-action input {
  border: 0.2em solid #333;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Funny Login Form</title>
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <form action="#" method="GET" class="border-curve">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="fieldset-container">
          <p class="form-title">Sign In With</p>

          <p class="form-social">
            <button class="border-curve">Facebook</button>
            <button class="border-curve">Google</button>
          </p>

          <p class="form-field">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input class="border-curve" type="text" name="username" id="username" />
          </p>

          <p class="form-field">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input class="border-curve" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
          </p>

          <p class="form-action">
            <input class="border-curve" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I should start to read the documentation.